# Can it be proven that an AWS accountID belongs to someone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My application needs the AWS account ID of its users in order to share AMI's and other stuff with them.

I want to be able to prove that this user is in fact the owner of that AWS account ID.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Would it be enough, for your use case, for that someone to prove that they *have access* to that account id? The subtle difference is: they are not proving the ownership of the account, they are just proving that the they have credentials with certain permissions within that account. In many circumstances, it will be equivalent. Would this be enough? Other than that, if you need really proof of *ownership* (instead of just proof of access), I don't think there's a way to do it...

Comment: @brunoreis perhaps.... are you saying there is a way to prove someone has access to that account?

Answer (score 3):

One way you could programmatically ascertain that your user *has access* to the account ID they give you, is to ask them to perform some actions in the account in a way that you can verify it.

Probably one of the most typical (and very secure) ways to do this is:

- ask your user to **create an IAM Role** in their account, for *Cross account access*, and then trust your account ID; this role could have extremely limited Access Policy (or even no permissions at all). Make sure you generate a unique External ID to make this more secure and ask the user to use it. Also, they should use a Role Name that you define, and you should try to make it fairly unique to avoid collisions with other roles that the user might already be using.
- your application then uses the Account ID provided by your user, the role name that you defined, and the External ID that you defined, and **you try to *AssumeRole* in their account**.

If your AssumeRole operation succeeds, it means that your user *can* create a Role in the account they claim to be the owner of.

That's probably as far as you can go.

---

A final note.

Other solutions I've seen around include asking the user to create an IAM User, generate AK/SK, then give you the AK/SK, and then you run some API calls on their account, using the AK/SK provided, to verify. **I strongly dislike this solution** because it's much less secure than the one above.

Comment: You may be right.  I was hoping to find a way that entirely avoids the need to get users to do stuff like create roles because I understand IAM and roles (I think - partially anyway), but  I suspect IAM and roles are really scary for people who don't understand IAM and roles (which I think is most people who use AWS).

Comment: I think I feel your pain... but that's probably the only way to do it: ask that the user perform an action -- with an externally observable side effect -- that just "the owner" (or someone on behalf of the owner) would be able to perform. Similar to many services around that ask the owner of a domain name to add a TXT record to confirm ownership...